Why am i getting this error while deploy FastAPI on vercel?
I'm getting this error, trying to host an API on FastAPI.
And this log on vercel's logs page.
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception. The most likely cause is an issue in the function code. However, in rare cases, a Lambda runtime update can cause unexpected function behavior. For functions using managed runtimes, runtime updates can be triggered by a function change, or can be applied automatically. To determine if the runtime has been updated, check the runtime version in the INIT_START log entry. If this error correlates with a change in the runtime version, you may be able to mitigate this error by temporarily rolling back to the previous runtime version. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html
[ERROR] TypeError: Queue.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 305, in vc_handler
   response = asgi_cycle(__vc_module.app, body)
 File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 202, in __call__
   self.app_queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)

And this log in builds logs page

[23:05:51.221] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[23:05:51.368] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[23:05:51.833] Downloading 4 deployment files...
[23:05:52.048] Restored build cache
[23:05:52.135] Running "vercel build"
[23:05:52.564] Vercel CLI 34.1.10
[23:05:52.709] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[23:05:52.732] Installing required dependencies...
[23:06:00.809] Build Completed in /vercel/output [8s]
[23:06:01.031] Deploying outputs...
[23:06:17.292] 
[23:06:17.538] Deployment completed
[23:06:18.157] Uploading build cache [29.00 B]...
[23:06:18.276] Build cache uploaded: 118.998ms```

 > Repo: https://github.com/Ernesto-Alves67/fastAPI_teste



- I have already tried everything discussed in this post [Vercel Deployment Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66840942/vercel-deployment-error-command-npm-run-build-exited-with-1)


